# Flask login form inside Bootstrap modal - how to handle form errors?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-wtforms

I've placed my login form inside a Bootstrap modal. If the form is valid it submits and the user is logged in, but I need a way to display validation errors/failed attempts inside the modal window.

I've only worked with forms that were constrained to one view until now. In those cases I was able to pass the form to the template (`render_template('foo.html', form=form)` which rendered the fields and handled errors with a [macro](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates).

The login modal I'm trying to create sits in the layout view which every template inherits, but the login form isn't passed by every view so the macro can't be used.

Form

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

View

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    form = forms.LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = models.User.get(models.User.username == form.username.data)
        except models.DoesNotExist:
            flash("Your username or password doesn't match")
        else:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                flash("You've been logged in!")
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                flash("Your username or password doesn't match")
```

Relevant modal code from layout template

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form method="post" action='{{ url_for("login") }}' name="LoginForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
        </div>
        <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say : *I don't know how to handle errors*, are u referring to cases where User does not exist or wrong user input (username or password...etc) ?

Comment: @IronFist Yes thanks for clearing that up, I should've done that in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best course of action would be to use the built-in functionality of [flash](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/) in flask. You could flash the message then redirect back to the page with the modal.

**Example:**

[image]